# ¿Cómo solucionar problemas con el BehaviorSubject en Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

tengo algunos problemas a la hora de trabajar en Angular con el BehaviorSubject, uno de los problemas es a la hora de inicializarlo en el constructor puesto que de despues de Parsear del localStorage un item y mandarlo como parametro al BehaviorSubject al inicializarlo en el constructor me marca error, el cual dice lo siguiente:
**"No se puede asignar un argumento de tipo "string | null" al parámetro de tipo "string".
El tipo 'null' no se puede asignar al tipo 'string'.ts(2345)"**

Igualmente despues de eliminar del localStorage mi item y ponerle al método next() del behaviorSubject un null, me marca el siguiente error:
**No se puede asignar un argumento de tipo "null" al parámetro de tipo "Admin".**

[image: En esta imagen se ve el primer error dentro del constructor]

[image: En esta se ve el error dentro del método logOut()]

Adjunto mi código:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {HttpClient,HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import {Response} from '../models/response';
import { Admin } from '../models/admin';


const httpOption={
  //En los headers de una Request el Contend-Type es el tipo de documento que se eviará a través de la solicitud
  headers:new HttpHeaders({'Contend-Type':'application/json'})
  }

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

//Este es el servicio para proveer el Token el cual se invoca en el login 

export class ApiauutentiusuarioService {



  //El uso del subject es para la logistica del inicio de sesión
    

    url:string="https://localhost:5001/api/Admin/login";

    private  adminSubject: BehaviorSubject<Admin>;

  constructor(private _http:HttpClient) {

      
this.adminSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Admin>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('admin')));

   }

login(email:string,password:string):Observable<Response>{
                                //Usamos la URL para conectarnos al API y le mandamos dos elementos (ES IMPORTANTE DECIR QUE LOS ELEMENTOS FUERON PREVIAMENTE RECOGIDOS EN EL BODY O CUERPO DEL LOGIN )
                                //El httpOption nos permite indicarle que se enviara un doc JSON
return this._http.post<Response>(this.url,{email,password},httpOption).pipe(

  map(respuesta =>{
    if (respuesta.exito == 1){
      
      const admin:Admin=respuesta.data;
        localStorage.setItem('admin',JSON.stringify(admin));

        this.adminSubject.next(admin);


    }


    return respuesta;
  } )

);


//Regresa un elemento de tipo Response que contendrá dentro de la data el token 




}


logOut(){

localStorage.removeItem('admin');
this.adminSubject.next(null);


}


/*El json que se envia es 
{

email:value,
password:value

}
*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usuario') || "[]"))
2. .next(null!)

Saludos!

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
mySubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.subscription = this.myService.mySubject.subscribe(data => {
      this.myData = data;
    });
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Para solucionar problemas con BehaviorSubject en Angular, debes verificar la inicialización, la suscripción, la emisión y la destrucción de la suscripción al BehaviorSubject.